# Group Policy Management - Mass registry change

Tags: windows-7, windows-registry, group-policy

I have a number of group policy objects that I need to change all registry keys in the preferences:\windows settings: registry\hkey_local_machine\software\Microsoft\windows NT\current version\print\printers\

I need to change the properties for all keys in this folder to say "apply once and do not reapply"

I have several group policy objects that need this change and would prefer not to open the preferences for each key and make this change (will take hours and hours)  Any advice on how I may be able to make a change for all keys in a folder?

Please help!

thanks,

Answer (score 2):

There are many questions that the answer could change my answer here...

My first preference would be to use powershell to modify the inf files (the physical container file for the GPO).  These can usually be found on the SYSVOL defined by the DC.  Typically at this address if not redirected or moved.

\UNC\SYSVOL\DOMAINFQDN\Policies{GUIDofOBject}\Machine\microsoft\windows nt\SecEdit\GptTmpl.inf

In the inf file you can find the setting you want to change, and then do find replace on all desired infs to make the change.  A powershell foreach loop should do the trick nicely. There are alos some powershell GPO modules available (although I dont beleive they can modify GPOs directly)

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee461027.aspx

Comment: I had hoped to be able to do it without powershell since I lack skills.  Looks like that is the only way.  Thanks for your advice, I'll get to it when I have a chance and let you know how it goes.